# What does the number next to a hot question in the supercollider mean?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

Its a pretty self contained question.

I know its not the votes for a question, and not the total views. Is it views in a certain time period?

The number I'm talking about is circled in the below image.

[image: Supercollider]

Comment: It's the question's "hotness" score.

Comment: @Yannis Thanks, I tried searching but supercollider got some strange hits on Google.

Comment: @Lego ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @ColeJohnson I... I... I just don't get it -_-